# How to copy a file from network drive using pentaho

Tags: etl, pentaho, data-integration

I have Accessed the FTP path by giving the credentials like below

[image: Accessing FTP Paths]

In the case of Common folders i accessed like this.

[image: Accessing network paths]

This works fine when my windows pc stores the network login passwords. I need to mention in the step itself, for that i which type of step i have to use or any other suggestions???

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that mounting network file systems is very OS specific. The FTPS step allows use of a password because that's defined in the FTP(S) protocol. The Copy Files step uses the OS's copy command, which doesn't have a mechanism for specifying a password.

To make this work when you're not logged in, you'll have to set up a scheduled job that logs in under your account and runs the job (Kitchen). I haven't messed with doing that in Windows Scheduler much; I've always had trouble getting it to run when I'm not logged in.

I use pgAgent to schedule my jobs under my domain account which works, but I have to specify full UNC path names. It doesn't retain my drive mappings.

Sorry I can't be more help. This is a disadvantage of PDI, which is Java based, on Windows. Accessing Windows specific technology can be tricky.

Comment: @brain Thanks for the Suggession...

i have tired in a way, using the shell commands to make the OS to authenticate the network dive...

(net use for windows...)